# How can I create a mixin that will work with CSS gradients?

Tags: css, less

I have the following in my code:

```
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
 top,
        white,
        #e5e5e5 88%,
        #d8d8d8
    );
    background: -webkit-gradient(
 linear,
        left top, left bottom,
        from(white),
        to(#d8d8d8),
        color-stop(0.88, #e5e5e5)
    );
```

and

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #8b8b8b,
    #a9a9a9 10%,
    #bdbdbd 30%,
    #bfbfbf
);
background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top, left bottom,
    from(#8b8b8b),
    to(#bfbfbf),
    color-stop(0.1, #a9a9a9),
    color-stop(0.3, #bdbdbd)
);
```

I would like to implement these as a mixin and use less. However it seems like I 
would need two mixins for this. Can someone explain how I could do this and what
two mixins to do this would look like. Sorry if this question is a bit simple but
I just started using mixins and I am trying to understand the way to code them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LESS [uses pattern matching](http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions), so you are correct that it would probably require two mixins (one taking one stop, the other taking two stops). The following code demonstrates this (it could probably be reduced further, but this keeps it fairly obvious what is going on). Note how the "name" is the same (in my case, `setTopGradient`), but the number of variables is different.

**CORRECTION**: Your question showed you using decimals for `webkit` stops, but that is not necessary according to [this page](https://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/). So I have ***updated*** the following code to just percentages.

**LESS**

```
.setTopGradient(@startClr, @endClr, @st1Clr, @st1Pos) {

   background: -moz-linear-gradient(
      top,
      @startClr,
      @st1Clr @st1Pos,
      @endClr
   );

   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      linear,
      left top,
      left bottom,
      from(@startClr),
      to(@endClr),
      color-stop(@st1Pos, @st1Clr)
   );
}

.setTopGradient(@startClr, @endClr, @st1Clr, @st1Pos, @st2Clr, @st2Pos) {

   background: -moz-linear-gradient(
      top,
      @startClr,
      @st1Clr @st1Pos,
      @st2Clr @st2Pos,
      @endClr
   );

   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      linear,
      left top,
      left bottom,
      from(@startClr),
      to(@endClr),
      color-stop(@st1Pos, @st1Clr),
      color-stop(@st2Pos, @st2Clr)
   );
}

.someClass1 {
.setTopGradient(white, #d8d8d8, #e5e5e5, 88%);
}
.someClass2 {
.setTopGradient(#8b8b8b, #bfbfbf, #a9a9a9, 10%, #bdbdbd, 30%);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.someClass1 {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e5e5e5 88%, #d8d8d8);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#d8d8d8), color-stop(88%, #e5e5e5));
}
.someClass2 {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8b8b8b, #a9a9a9 10%, #bdbdbd 30%, #bfbfbf);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8b8b8b), to(#bfbfbf), color-stop(10%, #a9a9a9), color-stop(30%, #bdbdbd));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me so well.

Comment: @Anne: I had decimals for `webkit` in my answer because you had them in your question. Further research showed that percentages seem to be just fine for `webkit` and makes the code easier.